# Problems with Rake When Using a Git Clone of a Rails Project with RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rvm

I have cloned a rails project from Ryan Bates (complex forms samples) and am having a problem with rake.  I titled the question generally because I suspect it's an issue with my setup/usage rather than the project itself.

The project I am trying to use is:

I am using `RVM on OSX` and my default ruby is `ruby-1.9.2-p290`.

Here are the steps I am doing in a terminal (starting in a new empty directory):

```
git clone https://github.com/ryanb/complex-form-examples.git
```

--Created the project without error

The first time I did this, after I changed dir to the "`complex-forms-examples`", I got an RVM warning which I had not seen before.  It was asking for some sort of permission which I granted.  It does not do this anymore when I repeat the clone in a new empty directory.

The warning mentioned that there is an .rvmrc file in the directory.  The contents are as follows (one line):

```
rvm 1.9.2@complex-form-examples --create
```

I then run 'bundle' and have no errors.

Then I try to run "rake db:migrate" and I get the following error:

> -bash: /Users/ken/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/bin/rake: /Users/ken/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No
>   such file or directory

I get the same error when I run rake by itself or with any other parameter.

I have no ruby 1.9.2-p136 so I don't know why it is trying to use that ruby.

`'rails s'` is starting the server without error

I am only having problems with this project (i.e. rake is still working fine in my other rails projects).

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: Can be similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7319262/problem-to-run-comand-rake/7319389#7319389. Have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be broken migration/upgrade of ruby, try this:

```
rvm 1.9.2@global,1.9.2@complex-form-examples do gem pristine
rvm 1.9.2@global do gem pristine rake
```

make sure there is no error reported, in case of errors you need to pristine all gems manually (like in the second line)

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you have issues with updating rvm, go this route:

```
rvm get head && rvm reload
rvm use 1.9.2@complex-form-examples --create --install
```

also make sure you trust .rvmrc properly (`cd` project dir first):

```
rvm rvmrc trust .
```

maybe not related but you might find this interesting: http://screencasts.org/episodes/how-to-use-rvm

Comment: I did the above and the rake command is broken with the same output as before.