# Models remain cached when running in development after upgrading to Rails 3.2

Tags: caching, model, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've upgraded a project from Rails 3.1 to Rails 3.2, and now, while in development, every time I update a model, I need to restart the server for the change to be effective. Changes in views and controllers are effective immediately.

I'm pretty sure it comes from the upgrade because none of my new projects in Rails 3.2 have this issue. I've checked the development.rb and application.rb from the old project against ones from new projects, and they're identical. I can't seem to find an answer on the net, would anybody know what I should do?

Cheers,
Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had `warning: already initialized constant` messages popping up all the time so I looked for a fix to this problem. Seems like its solution also fixed my cache problem.
Basically you have to uninstall rake and reinstall it via bundle... Answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7553276/1389981

Answer (score 0):

Try and have a look in your development.rb file. There should be a line with `config.cache_classes`, this should be set to `false`, to ensure that you don't need to restart the server to reflect changes you make to various classes:

```
# development.rb
config.cache_classes = false
```

Comment: Hey Emil, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately cache_classes is already set to false. I've tried comparing all files in the config folder with other apps where I don't have this problem, they seem identical... I might have missed something but no idea what.