# Rails 4 doesn't detect application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

After updating to Rails 4, I'm trying to start the server, but it won't start. Simply put, the application doesn't seem to get "detected", like there is no application in there.

```
~ $ bundle exec rails server
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]              # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                                 # Default: /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby
  -b, [--builder=BUILDER]        # Path to some application builder (...
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]      # Path to some application template (...
      [--skip-gemfile]           # Don't create a Gemfile
  -B, [--skip-bundle]            # Don't run bundle install
```

What is weird is that the (older) system gem will make it start just fine, but not with Bundler.

Why won't Rails start?

I tried navigating the CLI source code, but I can't grip what's going on.

(Using Edge Rails 4.0.0.beta and Ruby 2.0.0.rc)

In case you're wondering, here's the directory listing:

```
~ $ ls
app  config db    Gemfile   lib  mock    Rakefile   script  tmp
bin  config.ru  features  Gemfile.lock  log  public  README.md  spec    vendor
```

Comment: Are there any differences in the versions of the system gem and the Bundler gem? With which version did you generate the Rails app? Looks like you're trying to boot the Rails app with a different version than the actual apps is generate with.

Comment: You are most probably right. I think the thing is I'm using Edge and so the bootup code can change any time. I'm sorting it out by running `bundle exec rails new`. I'll post the solution soon, hopefully.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Rails 4 did change the way it boots up.

Fortunately, you don't have to run `rails-new`, since there is a handy task for that.

[Rails 4 Release Notes](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#railties-notable-changes):

> #### 6.1  Notable changes
>
> - Your app's executables now live in the `bin/` dir. Run `rake rails:update:bin` to get `bin/bundle`, `bin/rails`, and `bin/rake`.

Comment: Thanks for this. Though tonight's deployment still failed in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly, I've been had by my own laziness. (Even though laziness is the mother of efficiency ;o) ) I've made a point of [not using Bundle when running](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7553276/720164) Rails server.

Rails 4.0.0.beta [changes the way it boots up](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/009873aec89a4b843b41accf616b42b7a9917ba8). But, since I was using my "old" version of Rails, an older 4.0.0-beta I had lying around in my local gems, which didn't have the change, I didn't notice when the change was made to my bundle.

Now, when came the time to deploy, the obligatory `bundle-exec` couldn't boot because my code was used to boot the old way.

### The solution

Do like the message says to: `bundle exec rails new .`. And use Bundle this time! At that point, Rails will generate the boilerplate stuff, namely the missing boot files like `./bin/rails`.

It will also update some config files, and try to overwrite some stuff. In my case, everything is checked into source control, so there's a bit of diff'ing and choosing whether to overwrite or not and reverting after.

An maybe better idea (I haven't bothered to) would be to branch out in Git, run the "upgrade" `rails-new`, overwrite everything, commit that, and then three-way merge back with the main branch.

Answer (score 0):

If your bin folder is already in place, you may just need to run `bundle install` first. This solved the problem for me after cloning a repo that  was working perfectly on another machine.